# Laravel onDelete('cascade') does not work

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

My Tables:

```
 Schema::create('support_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
Schema::create('supports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('support_category_id')->onDelete('cascade')->constrained('support_categories')->nullable();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am getting following errors when I try to delete support_categories

`Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just write foreign key in wrong order.

Instead of:

```
$table->foreignId('support_category_id')->onDelete('cascade')->constrained('support_categories')->nullable();
```

Write:

```
$table->foreignId('support_category_id')->nullable()->constrained('support_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

or you can use casadeOnDelete():

```
$table->foreignId('support_category_id')->nullable()->constrained('support_categories')->casadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I migrate:refresh with batch number?

Comment: You can set amount of migrations to rollback like: php artisan migrate:rollback --step=3